# How do I make a phonenumber clickable/callable in desktop computers and in smartphones?

Tags: android, html, ios, browser

I want

```
<a href="callto/tel:1234567890">1234567890</a>
```

to be clickable in smartphones AND desktop computers. In smartphones I want it to dial the number written and in desktop computers I want it to use default phone application (e.g. Skype) to dial the number.

It seems `callTo` attribute is not w3c valid (or is this old information?) and `tel` doesn't seem to work with Skype. What's the general best solution to use here?

It would be good if the solution would be w3c valid as well, but not necessary.

Comment: Maybe you could do a @media query in your css to hide the tel version if it's a desktop and vice versa if it's a smartphone? ie `<a href="callto:010101010101" class="show-on-desktop">Skype me</a>< a href="tel:010101010101" class="show-on-smartphones">Tap to Call Me</a>' and in your css @media query just hide the irrelavant one

Answer (score 0):

This should work, try resizing your screen .

```css
   
.show-on-smartphones{display:none;}
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .show-on-desktop{display:none;}
  .show-on-smartphones{display:block;}
      
}
```

```html
<a href="callto:010101010101" class="show-on-desktop">Skype me</a><a href="tel:010101010101" class="show-on-smartphones">Tap to Call Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested Javascript code:

```
function ancorSwitch(){

var os="Unknown";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

if(os != "Unknown")
{
var x=document.getElementById("myancor");
  x.setAttribute("href", "callto:010101010101");
  x.innerHtml = "Call me";
}
else{
var x=document.getElementById("a");
  x.setAttribute("href", "tel:010101010101");
  x.innerHtml = "Call me";
}


}
```

in html, you write:

```
<a id="myancor"></a>
```

I can't check it myself,

if someone finds an error I'll fix it